# When should I use the "Get" or "Find" verbs in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I've been writing some basic PowerShell scripts for a while now and want to stick to the appropriate naming conventions by starting the name with approved verbs.
I can't see the difference between "Get" and "Find" though.

Supposing I make a script that searches Twitter for certain words should I call that Get-Tweets or Find-Tweets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get is for retrieving an object or resource. Find is for looking for the existence of an object or resource.

For more information, see the PowerShell documentation: [Approved Verbs for PowerShell Commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands)